# How to check the current isolation level setting in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, isolation-level

I'm trying to check **the current isolation level setting** in **Django**. For example, **the default isolation level setting** in **Django** is **`READ COMMITTED`** so if there is **`transaction.current_isolation_level()`**, I can print **`READ COMMITTED`** on console to check **the current isolation level setting** in **Django** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
    
    # Here
    print(transaction.current_isolation_level()) # READ COMMITTED

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

And if I set **`REPEATABLE READ`** for **the isolation level setting** in **Django** as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
    },
    'OPTIONS': {
        # Here
        'isolation_level': psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_REPEATABLE_READ,
    },
}
```

I can print **`REPEATABLE READ`** on console to check **the current isolation level setting** in **Django** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
    
    # Here
    print(transaction.current_isolation_level()) # REPEATABLE READ

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

So, are there such functions or variables to get **the current isolation level setting** in **Django**?

If no, how to check **the current isolation level setting** in **Django**?